# Millisecond timer using plain standard C++98

Tags: c++, timer

For development I'm using timer classes that are based on Win32 functions like `QueryPerformanceCounter()` or the time stamp counter of Intel-compatible CPUs. However, **for self-contained little test programs that can be posted here** (or put in a place like PasteBin and linked) I'm looking for a replacement that does not require Win32, Intel CPUs, or a C++11 compliant system (let alone humongous libraries like boost). And I don't want to require users to pull extra headers or .cpps from a place like GitHub.

In other words, the test programs should be truly self-contained, and they should not require C++ standard compatibility that goes beyond C++98 or at most C++03, in order not to exclude people who have to use older systems (or systems that lag the state of the art by up to a decade, like the Borland/Embarcadero compilers). Also, the timer source code shouldn't take up too much screen space, with oodles of `#ifdef`s and so on - that would detract from the main thrust of the test program, whatever it might be.

Here's what I've come up with so far, source-compatible with my standard timer class:

```
namespace util
{
   struct Timer  // minimal emulation of zrbj::Timer that doesn't require Win32, boost or C++11
   {
      typedef std::clock_t Ticks;
      Ticks t_;

      static Ticks GetTicks ()
      {
         return std::clock();
      }

      static double ms (Ticks ticks)
      {
         return ticks * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      }

      Timer (bool start_now = false) : t_(start_now ? GetTicks() : 0)  {  }

      Ticks Start ()  {  return t_ = GetTicks();  }
      Ticks Stop ()   {  return t_ = GetTicks() - t_;  }
      double ms () const {  return ms(t_);   }
   };
}

#ifndef ZRBJ_TIMER_HPP_INCLUDED
namespace zrbj
{
   using util::Timer;
}
#endif
```

This allows me to switch between my high-precision timer and the 'postable' portable timer by commenting the zrbj timer #include in or out, without causing linker errors. Yes, I know that the interface for `zrbj::Timer` looks a bit dated; it's no wonder - in most countries it would be old enough to vote. But I don't want to cause gratuitous incompatibility to a code base which in parts dates back all the way to BC++ 3.1.

However, the resolution of `std::clock()` is rather coarse at 1 millisecond, and even that is not guaranteed. Here's the test function I used to measure resolution:

```
template<class Timer>
void print_timer_resolution (unsigned number_of_measurements = 3)
{
   typedef typename Timer::Ticks Ticks;

   std::printf("\nnominal resolution is %1.4f ms for %s\n", Timer::ms(1), typeid(Timer).name());

   for (unsigned i = 0; i < number_of_measurements; ++i)
   {
      Ticks t0 = Timer::GetTicks(), t1, t2;

      do t1 = Timer::GetTicks(); while (t1 == t0);
      do t2 = Timer::GetTicks(); while (t2 == t1);

      std::printf("\nmeasured resolution:%8.4f ms", Timer::ms(t2 - t1));
   }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> *** VC++ 14.0 (x64) *** RTTI _CPPUNWIND 190023506.0
>
> nominal resolution is 1.0000 ms for struct util::Timer
>
> measured resolution:  1.0000 ms
> measured resolution:  1.0000 ms
> measured resolution:  1.0000 ms
>
> nominal resolution is 0.0003 ms for struct zrbj::Timer
>
> measured resolution:  0.0003 ms
> measured resolution:  0.0003 ms
> measured resolution:  0.0003 ms
> ```

A couple more compilers (without the lines for zrbj::Timer, which are identical to those of VC++ in all cases):

> ```
> *** g++ 4.8.1 64 ***
>
> nominal resolution is 1.0000 ms for N4util5TimerE
>
> measured resolution:  1.0000 ms
> measured resolution:  1.0000 ms
> measured resolution:  1.0000 ms
>
> *** BC++ 7.10 (RX/Seattle) 64 *** CLANG 3.3.1 (35465.f352ad3.17344af)
>
> nominal resolution is 1.0000 ms for N4util5TimerE
>
> measured resolution: 16.0000 ms
> measured resolution: 16.0000 ms
> measured resolution: 15.0000 ms
>
> *** BC++ 5.5.1 (free) 32 ***
>
> nominal resolution is 1.0000 ms for util::Timer
>
> measured resolution: 15.0000 ms
> measured resolution: 16.0000 ms
> measured resolution: 16.0000 ms
> ```

Borlandcadero doesn't even manage the usual 1 ms, and with other compilers/platforms the picture will be equally mixed.

The reason for not wanting to exclude people whose system is not state of the art is that I'm usually in that very same situation myself. I used my copy of C++Builder 3 Professional until XE2 came out, and I used XE2 until the release of RX/Seattle coincided with a bonus burning holes in my pocket. Yes, there are amazing compilers like gcc and VC++ to be had for no money, but the former doesn't have an IDE like C++Builder does (even though [DevCpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/) is very neat) and editions of VC++ newer than 2008 are very resource-hungry; none of them includes the interface-building capabilities and database support of C++Builder. In short, hobbyists often have short budgets, and so people may have reasons for using older systems as their main development/experimentation environment.

Can the situation be improved without incurring gratuitous incompatibilities? Or is there an elegant way for users to plug in their own favourite timer - like one based on `std::chrono`, boost or `<windows.h>` - without a lot of hassle? Something like an interposer `#include`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know, if there is a better solution in standard c++98 (I don't think so).But a few things came to my mind while reading: Have you had a look at QtCreator? Do you really need a High-res timer for show case examples? If the timer resolution is in any way important for the functionality of your code, then you probably should not replace your actual timer code in the first place. Finally, as you are not so much asking for a review of your existing code, but for a completely different mechanism / tool, I'd rather post such questions on SO, where they reach a broader audience.

Comment: @MikeMB - you raised good questions that aren't easy to answer. The reason for posting this here was that the timer is intended for use on Code Review, and thus any solution must be Code-Review-icly clean, so to speak. ;-) Also, there are quite a few bits that fall squarely under the purview of Code Review, like the trick with declaring the timer in another namespace and injecting it into the target namespace via a `using` declaration. IOW, I think the overall problem has a lot more to do with code craft than with the knowledge of hidden gems in standards headers...

Comment: A second reason was to write a Code Review article that sets a different focus than the usual "here's some poorly designed and sloppily coded sh*te" with the usual answers exclusively focussed on form, formatting and sleight-of-hand stuff. Hence the discussion of the whys and wherefores in addition to the what, since good code is always about the confluence of purpose and design, form and function.

Comment: @DartGizka: Don't get me wrong: I think your question is absolutely on topic here on CR and I wouldn't post it as it is on SO. However, for the specific part of how to get a high-res, platform independent c++89 timer, which I (maybe wrongly) thought was your main concern, I think you are more likely to get an answer on SO, simply because (I believe) there are more people looking at your question.